# System of differential equations (particular solution)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Find the general solution for:
$$y_1'=-y_1+3y_2 $$
$$y_2'=2y_1-2y_2 $$

Find the solution satisfying the initial condition $y(0)=\begin{pmatrix}
    5 \\
    0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$

From the equation above, $\lambda_1=1$ and $\lambda_2=-4$,

The general soltution is: $$c_1e^x\begin{pmatrix}
    3 \\
    2 \\
    \end{pmatrix} + c_2e^{-4x}\begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    -1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$$

I'm not sure how to use the condition above to find the particular solution.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  solve the linear system
$$c_1e^0\begin{pmatrix}
    3 \\
    2 \\
    \end{pmatrix} + c_2e^0\begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    -1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}=y(0)=\begin{pmatrix}
    5 \\
    0 
  \end{pmatrix},$$
that is
$$\begin{cases}
3c_1+c_2=5\\
2c_1-c_2=0
\end{cases},$$
for the constants $c_1,c_2$.